# Postgres to ActiveRecord Query for Custom Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, active-record-query

I'm running ruby 2.1.1p76 with Rails 4.1.5

I have 3 tables:
users
drivers
picks

simply put, users pick drivers.  The catch is, they can't pick the same driver more than twice.
The picks table is nothing more than a driver_id column and user_id column which is populated once the user selects a driver.

The form and inserts work beautifully right now without the validation in place.

I need to write a custom validation (I think) so a user cannot select the same driver more than twice.  The Postgres query that I believe will get me there is:

**SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_driver_id_user_id, driver_id AS driver_id, user_id AS user_id FROM "picks" GROUP BY driver_id, user_id HAVING count(*) = 2**

How do I make that into an ActiveRecord query for a custom validation?  essentially, when the driver is selected from the drop down list and the submit button is clicked, the query is run to make sure the count_driver_id_user_id column doesn't return 2 and if so, spit out an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the following custom validation works perfectly.  Inside the Picks model I created the following:

validate :max

private

def max
    unless Pick.where(user_id: user_id, driver_id: driver_id).count < 2
      errors.add(:user_id, 'You can only pick a driver twice')
    end
  end